Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct generate inconsistent output
I want to use Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct model, and although I have set "temperature": 0.0, "top_p":0.0 and "top_k":0, it still generates inconsistent output. This is how my pipeline looks like:
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model_id,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map="mps",
        model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.0,
                  "do_sample":True,
                              "top_p":0.0,
                              "top_k":0,},
)

Any idea how to solve this issue?

do_sample=True enables stochastic sampling, which inherently introduces randomness

The model inconsistent output can be due to two main factors:
1. Temperature:
setting temperature to zero give more inconsistent result. You can refer Opeani discussion page for detail.
So the best option is to set temperature to very low values such as 0.00001 instead of zero.
2. do_sample
You already set it false, and it should remain that way only.

thanks. It almost worked, now I get nearly consistent results. Can you please explain why 0.00001 gives more consistency than 0?

I have added the reference discussion page where community members have already explained the reason.

do_sample=True enables stochastic sampling, which inherently introduces randomness and also setting temperature=0.0, top_p=0.0, and top_k=0 attempts to make the output deterministi Huggingface pipelines
The configuation Iam using for one of my project like so
from transformers import pipeline
import torch

#pipeline
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model_id,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    device_map="mps",
    model_kwargs={
        "temperature": 0.0,
        "do_sample": False,  # False
        "num_beams": 1      # additional thing
    }
)

# Generate text
result = pipe(
    "Your prompt here",
    max_length=100,
    pad_token_id=pipe.tokenizer.pad_token_id,
    eos_token_id=pipe.tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    return_full_text=False
)


thanks for reply. when I "do_sample": False , I get warning : UserWarning: do_sample is set to False. However, temperature is set to 0.0 -- this flag is only used in sample-based generation modes. You should set do_sample=True or unset temperature. What is that and is it safe to ignore?

temperature set to 0.0does not affect the behavior of your pipeline as we are completly using deterministic methods for the results. you can simply remove thattemperature` parameter from the pipeline...
